# Infinitive of 'shall', 'should'?

Tags: verbs, single-word-requests

What's the infinitive of the verb when I say "I should go," or "I shall go"? Is it a verb actually, now that I think about it? If not, what is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Shall" and "Should" are [modal verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_auxiliary_verb) and don't have infinitive forms.

Notice that "to should" and "to shall" don't exist.

The only verb in your sentences that has an infinitive form is "go", for which the infinitive is "go".

That's because your sentence follows the typical structure of a sentence with modal verbs:

> [subject] [modal verb] [infinitive of
>   main verb]

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is a verb, see e.g. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shall) or [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shall#Verb). *Should* is a [past-tense form of *shall*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/should#English).

Answer (score 2):

the infinitive of ***should*** is ***to have to***. just like to the infinitive of ***can*** is ***to be able to***. I'm pretty sure since that's the italian to english translation of ***dovere*** and ***potere***